# Symfony 5 Doctrine Postgres connection over SSL

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to connect to an external Postgres server over SSL

I can connect without problems using PgAdmin4

[image: pgadmin4 connection over ssl]

I am trying to connect from my symfony 5 application but can't connect

doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
    url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
    server_version: '12.2'
    sslmode: 'verify-ca'
    sslrootcert: '%kernel.project_dir%/certs/ca-cert.pem'
    sslcert: '%kernel.project_dir%/certs/client-cert.pem'
    sslkey: '%kernel.project_dir%/certs/client-key.pem'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5433/dbname
```

error

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] root certificate file "C:UsersAugustoPhpstormProjectsecofil/certs/ca-cert.pem" does not exist
>   Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.

```
root@SQLECOFIL1:/var/log/postgresql# tail -f postgresql-12-main.log
xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx 2020-05-10 19:29:20.459 CEST [2457] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: Success
```

help!! thanks

Comment: `C:UsersAugustoPhpstormProjectsecofil`  The lack of slash after `C:` seems significant here.  And maybe in more places in that string

Comment: thanks. Solve by using C:\\Users\\Augusto\\PhpstormProjects\\ecofil\\certs\\
Do you know i can i solved using symfony vars like this? %kernel.project_dir%

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that.